# visual c++: convert int into string pointer

Tags: visual-c++

how to convert integer into string pointer in visual c++?

Comment: What is a string pointer? Can you give some example about the input and the expected output?

Comment: input is suppose 489.
then i want to convert this in "489" so that i can how this in some textbox ...

Comment: i tried sprintf command , s.format command char*=(char*)(567\\any integer)but it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Use stringstream

```
#include <sstream>
stringstream ss;
ss << i;
string   s = ss.str();
```

Comment: visual c++ is not taking 
#include <sstream>
header file so this methid is not workable.

Comment: visual c++ should take sstream.. there must be something wrong with your setup. This is definately the preferred/safer way to do it. char*, atoi, sprintf, etc all open the door for the programmer to make errors. It is best to be safe and stick to using std::string instead of char*, and stringstream for conversions. This comes at the expensive of performance... but barely. For most applications this will do fine

Comment: come on guy, why not write your own itoa but use low perfromance string or CString? btw, sprintf is slow too. you got bad idea

Answer (score 2):

If you using CString, then you can use Format() method like this:

```
int val = 489;
CString s;
s.Format("%d", val);
```

Comment: CString is a safe API and this solution is the simplest and most elegant.

Answer (score 2):

search for [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) / [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) in your favorite documentation. Or try Boost ([www.boost.org](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) - library Conversion, lexical_cast).

Both ways are portable across different compilers.

Comment: I prefer lexical_cast myself. It looks cleaner than std::stringstream and itoa. PLus itoa is listed as "non-standard" on cplusplus.com. I know boost isn't technically standard either, but I figure it's better than relying on your compiler to have a non-standard cstdlib function.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very easy method

```
int i=4;
String ^ s = Convert::ToString(i);
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution which worked for me in Visual Studio 2010 without including any extra header files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a textual representation of the pointer address use [sprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf(VS.71).aspx).
If you want to treat the numeric value as a pointer to a string use casting like so:

```
int intValue = ...;
char * charPtr = (char*)intValue;
```

Comment: He said convert, so I'm pretty sure he means turning 123 into "123", not a cast.

Comment: this command is worable if one wants to convert in char pointer but this is not working for converion to string pointer.

Comment: @GMan yes exactly , iwant to convert 123 in  "123".
how to do that?

Comment: I would say do what pierr is suggesting in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take any C and C++ textbook. This simple C code should work in Visual C++ and others C++ compilels and convert 489 into "489":

```
char result[100];
int num = 489;
sprintf(result, "%d", num);
```

Answer (score 0):

basic C++

```
char text[100];
int num=123;
itoa(num,text,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in my homework since we were only allowed to use some predetermined libraries. I'm pretty sure it's not considered a "best practice" though ;)

```
string int2string(int integer) {
    string str;
    int division = integer;

    while (division > 0) {
        str = char('0' + (division % 10)) + str;
        division = division / 10;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest one would be:

```
int i;
String s=i.toString();
// It is about Visual C++
```

Answer (score -1):

You got homework? a generic one, tested if g++, http://effocore.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/devel/effo/codebase/addons/inl/include/impl/algo_impl.h
:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus

static inline char *int2a_put(uintptr_t i, char *s)
{
    do {
        *s++ = '0' + i % 10;
        i /= 10;
    } while (i);

    return s;
}

static inline void int2a_reverse(char *head, char *tail)
{
    for (*tail = '\0'; --tail > head; ++head) {
        /* exchange */
        (*head) ^= (*tail);
        (*tail) ^= (*head);
        (*head) ^= (*tail);
    }
}

template<typename t>
static inline const char *int2a(t i, char *s)
{
    char *p;
    char *ret = s;
    bool f = false;

    p = s;
    if (i < 0) { 
        *p++ = '-';
        ++ s;
        /* 
         * In limits.h, INT_MAX was defined as 
         *   maximum values a `signed int' can hold.
         * and LONG_MAX was defined as maximum values 
         *   a `signed long int' can hold. 
         */
        switch (sizeof(t)) {
        case 8:
            {
                /* 
                 * Inject \p a to prevent from complaint 
                 *   of compiler.
                 */
                ef64_t a = (ef64_t)i;
                if (-LLONG_MAX > a) {
                    i = (t)LLONG_MAX;
                    f = true;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 4:
        case 2:
        case 1:
            {
                /* 
                 * Inject \p a to prevent from complaint 
                 *   of compiler. 
                 */
                int a = (int)i;
                if (-INT_MAX > a) {
                    i = (t)INT_MAX;
                    f = true;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        if (!f) {
            i = -i;
        }
    }

    p = int2a_put((uintptr_t)i, p);

    if (f) {
        ++ *s;
    }

    int2a_reverse(s, p);

    return ret;
}

/*
 * No "static" otherwise g++ complains 
 *   "explicit template specialization cannot have a storage class"
 */
template<>
/*static*/ inline 
const char *int2a<uintptr_t>(uintptr_t i, char *s)
{
    char *p = int2a_put(i, s);

    int2a_reverse(s, p);

    return s;
}

#else
```