# Visual c++: putting a integer into text box

Tags: visual-c++

in my program when i will click button then i want to show some integer into textbox as out.
but textbox is taking only string pointer.  how to sort out this problem then?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552940/visual-c-convert-int-into-string-pointer You are using multiple logins?

Comment: i not know about this question 
but this Question is seem to solve my problem 
i will try given methodsin that Question.

Comment: in the stackoverflow.com/questions/1552940/…  QUestion method suggested are not working.      
please suggest if have any new technique to solve the above said problem       in my problem ,while debuuging it is given error that it is not converting int in string ^.

Answer (score 0):

To set the text of a dialog item to a number, you can use the [SetDlgItemInt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645518%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.