# Visual C++: displaying integer in a text Box

Tags: visual-c++

I want to write

```
int i=4;
textBox1->Text = i;
```

But it is giving compilation error for type mismatch. How to do box or typecast this?

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552940/visual-c-convert-int-into-string-pointer/1553063#1553063

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need conversion, not a cast. Use `itoa()` or `itow()` depending on whether you compile for Unicode.

Comment: These dont work in Visual C++. It says "Cannot convert from char * to String ^

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering the quesition myself. But I just got it while searching.
There is a very easy method

```
int i=4;
textBox1->Text = Convert::ToString(i);
```

Comment: You are using managed c++ thus you need to look at the .Net libraries

Answer (score 1):

Instead you could use: `textBox1->Text = i.ToString();`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very easy method

```
int i=4;
textBox1->Text = ""+i;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using CString you can use Format method, or use old c function itoa

example:

```
CString str;
str.Format("%d",i);
```

also do not forget to call UpdateData method to update the GUI controls

Answer (score 0):

Convert integer to string and set as value for Text.

```
CString textVal;
textVal.Format(_T("%d"), i);
textBox1->Text = textVal;
```